# Cocoa app without a MainMenu.xib

Tags: cocoa, delegates, xib

For iOS (Cocoa Touch), it's possible to go to your main.m and replace the fourth argument in `UIApplicationMain(int argc, char *argv[], nil, nil)` with the class name of your app's delegate, which would then construct the views as needed. However, Cocoa (Mac) projects have the following in main.m:

```
    return NSApplicationMain(argc, (const char **)argv);
```

So the question is basically: how do you hand over an app's delegate to Cocoa apps without a MainMenu.xib?

Comment: This isn't actually a good idea, since MainMenu.xib contains the menu bar. So, anybody who looks for a solution, don't look for it unless you want to take the pain of recreating and filling the content of the menu bar on your own. What's why MainMenu.xib is called MainMenu.xib :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `setDelegate` method of `NSApplication` instance. Here is a sample:

```
AppDelegate * delegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] setDelegate:delegate];
[NSApp run];
```

As for return value you can use `EXIT_SUCCESS`

Comment: That works, thanks. You know what, I just realized the MainMenu.xib has the menu bar, and recreating it is gonna be such a pain so I'll just stick with the main xib.

Comment: You are welcome. I think its better to write down a few lines instead of editing menu)

Comment: but what would be the return value ?

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `NSApplication`, declare your subclass's name as the `Application Class` (or similar) property in Xcode. In your subclass you may override some function that gets called when the app is initialized, maybe `-finishLaunching`?

Comment: I was able to successfully subclass NSApplication and override its init to point to the delegate (the delegate then responded with my NSLog's in applicationDidFinishLaunching). However, the app still picks up MainMenu.xib even if the main nib file entry is deleted from the property list. And if you delete the MainMenu.xib itself the app crashes on launch without anything significant in the debugger